# UIAppearance, see result in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, interface-builder

I'm using `UIAppearance` a lot for my navigation controllers and other UI objects, and I was wondering if it's possible to have my related objects styled in Interface Builder (maybe with some magic voodoo of `@IBDesignable`?)

Comment: Did you try it? You'd presumably need to use `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` to set things up. If that doesn't work, then the answer is No.

Comment: Yes I tried it on the App Delegate, but didn't work :/

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "on the app delegate". The app delegate is not an IBDesignable. Its code is not running just because you use IB. You would need to have a IBDesignable view and (as I already suggested) implement its `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`.

Comment: I gave it a try on the App delegate as well as on Custom UIView but nada. I simply suppose this is not possible.. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 7):

matt's comments on the question are correct. You're able to successfully use UIAppearance proxies in the `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` method.

Example:

```
@IBDesignable
class MyCustomView: UIView {

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        MyCustomView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

This will result in all `MyCustomView` instances to be rendered red in IB.

Comment: How about UIAppearance on all the navigation bar tint color? I usually do in my app delegate something like `UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.appBrandColor()`

Comment: @allaire: It doesn't seem to work for UINavigation bars.

Comment: using only `backgroundColor = .red` inside `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` will actually do the same. I don't see the point using UIAppearance in this context 

Comment: @itMaxence imagine having a single view in your hierarchy set the uiappearance proxies for your entire app. This allows centralization of where you see your themes instead of distributing the settings throughout your hierarchy.